# Could not find wheel packages using pip command on CentOS?

Tags: python, centos, pip, python-wheel

If I am running pip install scipy on Ubuntu, pip finds whl package and installs it but for centos, it tries to download the source and compile and install it explicitly. I have observed this with lots of packages while installing on centos I would like to know is there anything I can do on centos so pip can safely find packages and install them. At the same time I would like to get those whl packages on centos

Comment: Check what platform/ABI `pip` reports on your system: run `python -c "import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_platform())"` and `python -c "import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_abi_tag())"`, what output do you get?

Comment: Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-XuDVyh/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ZhvS9z-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-XuDVyh/scipy/

Comment: This is the generic error of an installation failure that `pip` reports.